# Why aren't my images geotagged?

Tags: gps, location-services, exif

I have a Blackview A60Pro running Android 9.

Location is enabled (Settings -> Security & location -> Location is "On")

The Camera app has all the permissions it requests, including Location (both "access approximate location (network-based)" and "access precise location (GPS and network-based)")

Location is enabled in the Camera app settings.

I read [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36082/why-are-my-photographs-not-stored-with-gps-location) and downloaded [My GPS location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digrasoft.mygpslocation) to make sure I have a GPS fix before taking pictures.

But the resulting JPEG files don't have any location information in the EXIF data. **What am I missing?**

Comment: I don't know what Camera app the Blackview uses, but have you tried 3rd-party Camera apps? Also, is the Camera app shown on the history of recent access on the Location setting? I just tested Google Camera (not available on Play Store) on Pixel 3a and the GPS location is stored in the "Composite" section, "GPS Latitude/Longitude/Altitude" fields.

Comment: "have you tried 3rd-party Camera apps?" I've just downloaded [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) and it's recording GPS location!